# Date Comparison Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var discover = $filter("date")(new Date('08-24-2015'), "MM/dd/yyyy");
var occur = $filter("date")(new Date('06-07-2018'), "MM/dd/yyyy")
console.log(discover);
console.log(occur);
if (discover < occur) {
    console.log('Discover less than occur');
} else {
    console.log('No');
}
```

The result is always **No** to whatever value I assign to discover variable.

Did I compare it wrong?

Comment: Found the error. I forgot the ; This is closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use momentJS for date-time operations. It is much cleaner to implement.

To check if a certain time is before or after another time you could use their [query functions](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/)

```
moment('2010-10-20').isBefore('2010-12-31', 'year'); // false
moment('2010-10-20').isBefore('2011-01-01', 'year'); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("BaseController", function($scope,$filter) { 
  
  var discover = $filter("date")(new Date('05-24-2015'), "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var occur = $filter("date")(new Date('06-07-2018'), "MM/dd/yyyy")
  console.log(discover);
  console.log(occur);
  if (discover < occur) {
      console.log('Discover less than occur');
  } else {
      console.log('No');
  }
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="BaseController">
 
  </body>

</html>
```